# ASP.NET Active Directory Membership Login Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

This is a very strange issue. I have setup a web application that uses Active Directory authentication to authenticate users to the application. It does not use the ASP.NET Membership Provider. It works great - except for one user. They attempt to login (and I have sat and watch them do this) with their AD username and password and they get the following error message from the login control:

> Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

Now, I have seen elsewhere that this issue can be caused by not setting the applicationName in the web.config file [when using the ASP.NET membership provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/443634.aspx) but I am NOT using the ASP.NET membership provider.

They can log into all other AD applications without issue. Including ones that integrate via PHP and the native Windows login, etc., but not into this application. Help!

Further Explanation:

Security Roles (which control permissions) are baked into the application...so it isn't using AD permissions at all for determining access, it just ensures that the user is a valid AD user who can authenticate to AD, once it does this it uses the local application to determine security roles and provide valid permissions...but the user is getting a login error at the point where the app tries to authenticate to AD...even though they are entering correct info. and are able to access all other AD systems (and we even did a password reset just to be safe).

Comment: Is the web application proprietary, or do you have access to the source code driving the login control?  Can other users login into this particular application without any problems?

Comment: I wrote the web application, so I have access to the login control. The login control is a standard ASP.NET Webforms login control. Other users can login to this particular application without issues.

Comment: Can you try a very simple AD bind with that user and password using command-line tool or `ActiveDirectory` classes in .NET, and see if you get any more specific messages?